# Remove punctuation from list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, tensorflow, punctuation

I am working on setting up some usable data for semantic analysis. I have a corpus of raw text data that I am iterating over. I open the data, read it as a string, split into a list, and prepare the data to be built into a dataset in a later function. However, when I build the dataset, my most common words end up being punctuation. I need to remove all punctuation from the list before I process the data further.

```
import os
import collections
import string
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from six.moves import xrange


totalvocab = []

#Loop for: loop through all files in 'Data' directory
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('Data'):
for file in files:
    filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
    print(filepath)

    #Function for: open file, convert input to string, split into list
    def read_data(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read()).split()
        return data

    #Run function on data, add file data to full data set.
    filevocab = read_data(filepath)
    totalvocab.extend(filevocab)

    filevocab_size = len(filevocab)
    print('File vocabulary size: %s' % filevocab_size)
    totalvocab_size = len(totalvocab)
    print('Total vocabulary size: %s' % totalvocab_size)
```

If I do the following:

```
def read_data(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read())
            data.translate(string.punctuation)
            data.split()
        return data
```

The words are split into individual letters.
Any other methods I have attempted have errored out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in the code:

1. `str.split()` and `str.translate()` do not modify in place.
2. `str.translate()` expects a mapping.

To fix:

```
def read_data(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read())
    data = data.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return data.split()
```

Removing punctuation, may or may not do what you want, e.g. hyphenated words will become concatenated. You could alternatively identify punctuation that you would replace with a space.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did exactly what I needed.

And you are also correct in predicting my future needs, as hyphenated words need to be included in my data. How would I go about declaring which punctuation to replace?